# handle mdl table check box

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-design-lite

I'm using material desigin lite in my website 
I have implemented this example:
http://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html#tables-section

```
<table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-data-table--selectable mdl-shadow--2dp">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Material</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Unit price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Acrylic (Transparent)</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>$2.90</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Plywood (Birch)</td>
          <td>50</td>
          <td>$1.25</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>$2.35</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

my question is how to handle the check box in the table , they are added by the class : .mdl-data-table--selectable

there is no Id or class for them so what is the way to use them in javascript or sql server (deleting rows what i'm trying to implement)

Comment: Material Design Lite is a web client-side library (like Twitter Bootstrap or Angular.js), it has nothing to do with server-side logic or databases.

Comment: @Dai yes true . but my question is more focused on the check box and how to handle them ,they are added just by using the class "mdl-data-table--selectable"
so i have no control of them by id or tag name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check if they're are clicked with a jquery on method, why am not using the normal .click is to because of [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). Jquery docs do a perfect job explaining that.

**Before I explain how I did it I will have a snippet that you can immediately play with under my explanation.**

I basically used inspect element to look at the tables structure and it looked something like this

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <label>clickable checkbox code</label>
    </td>
    <td>Acrylic</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>$2.90</td>
```

With that information, we can do a lot. I personally used this to listen to clicks.

```
$(document).on("click",".mdl-checkbox__ripple-container.mdl-js-ripple-effect.mdl-ripple--center", function() {  /* Code here*/ });
```

And with jquery [parents](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) & [children](https://api.jquery.com/children/) methods we can achieve a lot, like read the content of all the table data with the following code in our click event listener

```
 foo = $(this).parents().eq(2).children().text();
```

Or we can perhaps delete a whole row?

```
$(this).parents().eq(2).fadeOut();
```

What that would do is, look at the clicked checkbox using "this" as reference. Then go to levels up and remove a whole row.

```
<tr><!-- eq 2 -->
   <td> <!-- eq 1 -->
        <label>clickable checkbox code</label>
   </td>

   <td>Acrylic</td>
   <td>25</td>
   <td>$2.90</td>
```

Or we can check for the content of a specific child like this

```
 var secondChildContent = $(this).parents().eq(2).children().eq(2).text();
```

Where secondChildContent will be return the content. You can always change the eq (The one after children) value to the desired child number you want. In the following case secondChildContent  would return "Acrylic"

```
<tr>
<td> <!-- eq 1 -->
    <label>clickable checkbox code</label>
</td>

<td>Acrylic</td> <!-- eq 2 -->
<td>25</td> <!-- eq 3 -->
<td>$2.90</td> <!-- eq 4 -->
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on("click", ".mdl-checkbox__ripple-container.mdl-js-ripple-effect.mdl-ripple--center", function() {

    //Removing row
    $(this).parents().eq(2).delay(500).fadeOut(300);

    var secondChildContent = $(this).parents().eq(2/*child number*/).children().eq(2).text();
    var allChildrenContent = $(this).parents().eq(2).children().text();
    var parentID = $(this).parents().eq(2).attr('id');

    //Removing table on click of first checkbox
    if (parentID == "header") {
      $("#mdlTable").fadeOut(1000);
      $("#log").html("<b>Table removed!</b>");
    } else {
      //Don't pay attention to this
      $("#log").html(
        "<b>Second child content is: </b>" + secondChildContent +
        "<br><b>All children content is: </b>" + allChildrenContent
      )
    }

  });

});
```

```css
#log,
#mdlTable {
  margin: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Table</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.4/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
  <script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.4/material.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>

<body>
  <table id="mdlTable" class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-data-table--selectable mdl-shadow--2dp">
    <thead>
      <tr id="header">
        <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Material</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Unit price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Acrylic (Transparent)</td>
        <td>25</td>
        <td>$2.90</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Plywood (Birch)</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>$1.25</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>$2.35</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div id="log"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: really useful snippet ,so i need to scan "checked" boxes by the class 
"mdl-checkbox__ripple-container.mdl-js-ripple-effect.mdl-ripple--center" ?
or this returns all the check boxes ?(checked and unchecked)?

from what i understand from the snippet that the check box that get clicked on gets deleted , but doesn't check it's value (checked or not)
this is what i'm looking for...

Comment: It wont return all "checkboxes" notice how I make use of "this" as jquery selector. Which would look at the clicked element, and not at all elements with the class that has been clicked on. Also its pretty hard to figure out what you're trying to achieve here. If I personally needed to check whether a checkbox is checked or not. I would just use the jquery toggleclass method and toggle a custom class like "checked" or something. I would really appreciate it if you could be more specific about how you are willing to use the checkboxes.

Comment: i want to collect all the checked boxes and delete them using a post method (i'm deleting from sql server too but not important)
I believe you got to the right answer with the class "mdl-checkbox__ripple-container.mdl-js-ripple-effect.mdl-ripple--center"
now i can check value="checked" of the checked boxes .
i'm using javascript , but i'm following your jquery (i'm beginner at it)

Answer (score 1):

When a checkbox is selected, the tr gets the class "is-checked" with Material Design Lite. 
So your jquery can be like this:

```
$("table").find("tr.is-checked").each(function(){
        // Do some stuff!
    });
```

Update: Just read that the class "mdl-data-table--selectable " is being deprecated... [This is the article on github](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/wiki/Deprecations#automatic-selection-checkboxes)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this OnClick API function.
It uses like Android onClickListener, but it is for JavaScript.

```
TablesOnClickListener = function() {
var fun;
this.setOnClickListener = function(listener) {
    fun = listener;
    $(document).on("click", ".mdl-checkbox__ripple-container.mdl-js-ripple-effect.mdl-ripple--center", function() {
        //$(this).parents().eq(2).delay(500).fadeOut(300);
        var secondChildContent = $(this).parents().eq(2 /*child number*/ ).children().eq(2).text();
        var allChildrenContent = $(this).parents().eq(2).children().text();
        var parentID = $(this).parents().eq(2).attr('id');
        fun({
            sen: secondChildContent,
            text: allChildrenContent,
            id: parentID
        });
    });
}
```

How to use:

Step 1: create new TablesOnClickListener

```
var tocl = new TablesOnClickListener()
```

Step 2: set Item OnClickListener

```
tocl.setOnClickListener(function(data){
      console.log(data);
    });
```

Now your Tables Item Listener are all set!